# How can I fill out blank spaces in a text file with the word from the line above?

Tags: powershell, sed, grep

I have a large report file (about 20MB) that looks like this:

```
 586  700006207        8,622.09  896 
                       9,882.82  896 
 777   68607099          900.00  896 
 587  800006207        7,059.22  896 
                         959.02  896 
                         697.87  896 
   7  280667985             .00  899
```

On 1st and 2nd columns there are blanks if the values are the same as the line above. I need help with a grep/sed/powershell one-liner to fill out the empty spaces, so that it looks like this:

```
 586  700006207        8,622.09  896 
 586  700006207        9,882.82  896 
 777   68607099          900.00  896 
 587  800006207        7,059.22  896 
 587  800006207          959.02  896 
 587  800006207          697.87  896 
   7  280667985             .00  899
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;$!N;/^\(\( [0-9]\+ *[0-9]\+\).*\n\)\( \{15\}\)/{s//\1\2/;ta};P;D' file
```

From the data you have provided the line always begins with a space. If this is not the case then:

```
sed ':a;$!N;/^\(\([0-9]\+ *[0-9]\+\).*\n\)\( \{14\}\)/{s//\1\2/;ta};P;D' file
```

Comment: the first line worked great!!! I'm running the gnu unix tools on windows xp, so I had to use double quotes. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are not blank lines and the inter-column delimiters are spaces, the following works (tested in Ubuntu/bash shell, using GNU sed)...

```
sed -r "/^ {15}/{G; s/^ {15}(.*)\n(.{15}).*/\2\1/};h" "report"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to keep the spacing and the first 2 columns are the first 15 chars:

```
awk '
    NF==2 {print fill substr($0, 16); next}
    {print; fill = substr($0, 1, 15)}
'
```

Comment: thx glenn, i have no way to test it because i don't have awk, but it looks simple enough.